# How to write a SQL Server query to summarise table data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with a SQL Server query. I have a table like this:

```
user_id     display_name          username              updated_on
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2012772                           User1.UserName        450958885
2012772     User1.DisplayName                           451124897
2155281                           User2.UserName        451045840
2162145                           User3.UserName        451147363
2162145     User3.DisplayName                           451147423
```

and I need output like below: if display name for a user is present render that along with updated_on else render username and its updated on.

```
user_id     display_name_computed   updated_on
----------------------------------------------------
2012772     User1.DisplayName       451124897
2155281     User2.UserName          451045840
2162145     User3.DisplayName       451147423
```

The SQL should be with select statement. no temp tables or table variables usage. no delete statements usage.

Comment: Can you share some queries you've already tried?

Comment: Does the table contain at most one `username` and at most one `display_name` per `user_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go

```
select user_id
  , coalesce(max(display_name), max(username)) as display_name_computer
  , max(updated_on) as updated_on
from yourtable
group by user_id
```

Comment: This will probably return inconsistent results if `username` happens to have been updated later than `display_name`.